# Rails 4 collection_select not autofilling on render

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

So basically, I have a new view, and when the input fails, I want the view to re render with the previously inputted data.  For some reason, everything loads up the original request's data except the collection_selects in the form_for helper. I'm not really sure at all why.

```
  <%= form_for(@match) do |f| %>
    <b> Winner </b>
    <%= f.collection_select :user0_id, User.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>

    <b> Loser </b>
    <%= f.collection_select :user1_id, User.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>

    <b> Score </b>
    <%= f.select :score,  (0..21) %>

    <b> Password </b>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit match", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

and my controller:

```
def new
   @match = Match.new
end

def create

@match = Match.new(match_params)

if !match.save?
  flash.now[:notice] = "Match was not saved!"
  render :new
else
  # success code here
end
```

I'm verifying that the params hash gets sent back with all the correct values, but for some reason, it's not autofilling collection_select. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us the params hash that gets sent back?

Comment: authenticity_token: ---------------
     match: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
       user0_id: '15'
       user1_id: '56'
       cupsleft: '5'
       password: ''
     commit: Submit match
     action: create
     controller: matches
Could it possibly be the fact that user0, user1 are just attr_accessors in match.rb and not actual data attributes?  Each match has many users through a relation, and I don't know how to pass the users as an array attribute, so its kind of hacky.

Comment: hmmm... the value of user0_id and user1_id are what decide which values to autopopulate the collection_set, let me do some experimentation and see what I come up with.